# Ошибка:"Вызвано исключение:Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized."

Tags: c++

Как решить проблему? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std :: cout;
using std :: cin;
using std :: endl;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "russian");

    double a, b, c;
    double d;
    double x, x2;

    cout << "Enter a,b,c" << endl;
    cout << "a=";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b=";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "c=";
    cin >> c;

    d = (b*b) - (4 * a* c);
    cout << "D=" << d << endl;

    if (d < 0)
        cout << "No roots!" << endl;
    if (d == 0)
        x = -b / (2 * a);
    cout << "X=" << x << endl;
    if (d > 0)
        x = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    cout << "X1=" << x << endl;
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    cout << "X2=" << x2 << endl;


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас при условии `if (d < 0)` лишь выводится на консоль, что у уравнения нет корней. Переменная `x` при этом никакого значения не приобретает, однако Вы всегда пытаетесь вывести её значение на консоль. В Вашем коде явно не хватает фигурных скобок, попробуйте вот такое решение:

```
if (d < 0) {

    cout << "No roots!" << endl;
} else if (d == 0) {

    x = -b / (2 * a);
    cout << "X=" << x << endl;
} else {

    x = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    cout << "X1=" << x << endl;
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    cout << "X2=" << x2 << endl;
}
```